# Arm templates "mul" function for combining 2 arrays

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

So I have a template that is going to deploy multiple private endpoints in a Cosmosdb.
For it I have a Vnet Array with 5 Vnets:

```
"vnetArray": {
  "type": "array",
  "defaultValue": [
    "Vnet-1ab-1",
    "Vnet-2ab-8",
    "Vnet-3ab-9",
    "Vnet-4ab-34",
    "Vnet-5ab"
  ],
```

And also inside those vnets 4 subnets. Subnets are named the same in all the vnets.

```
"subnetArray": {
  "type": "array",
  "defaultValue": ["Subet-a","Subnet-b","Subnet-c","Subnet-d"],
  "metadata": {
  }
```

This will give 20 different private enpoints which will need to have their unique name like:
***"subnet-a-1ab-1-privateendpoint"***
So I have this following copy function code that uses the "mul" function to get number of private endpoints doing multiplication between subnets and vnets:

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('privateEndpointVersion')]",
  "copy":{
    "name": "peLoop",
    "count": "[mul(length(parameters('vnetArray')), length(parameters('subnetArray')))]"
  },
  "name": "[concat(parameters('subnetArray')[copyIndex('peLoop')], '-mongo-pe-', replace(parameters('vnetArray')[copyIndex('peLoop')], 'Vnet-', ''))]",
  "location": "[parameters('regionArray')[copyIndex()]]",
  "properties": {
    "customNetworkInterfaceName"
```

The problem is that I´m receiveing this error and not sure what can be related to.

```
{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[concat(parameters('subnetArray')[copyIndex('privateEndpointLoop')], '-mongo-pe-', replace(parameters('vnetArray')[copyIndex('peLoop')], 'Vnet-', ''))]' at line '97' and column '9' is not valid: The language expression property array index '5' is out of bounds.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-functions for usage details.'."}
```

So how you can use the mul function the get he number of total components and refer them in the copyIndex propertly? There isn´t on internet much examplex related to what I´m trying to get.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CopyIndex() language expression property array index '5' is out of bounds:

After analysing the error, it appears that the issue is with the `copyindex()` function in your code. The function `copyindex()` returns the index of the current iteration of the `copy()` loop. Array index out of bounds occurs when an array reaches its maximum limit and exceeds the index limit specified in the `parameters` block.

To avoid this conflict, use ARM [`mod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric#mod) & [`div`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric#div) numeric functions in the `name` property of `private endpoints` resource.

*After doing few modifications to your code, it worked as expected which is given below.*

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetArray": {
    "type": "array",
    "defaultValue": [
    "Vnet-1ab-1",
    "Vnet-2ab-8",
    "Vnet-3ab-9",
    "Vnet-4ab-34",
    "Vnet-5ab"
  ]},
  "subnetArray": {
  "type": "array",
  "defaultValue": ["Subet-a","Subnet-b","Subnet-c","Subnet-d"]
  }
  },
  "variables":{
      "privateEndpointName": "xxxxx"
  },
  "resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
  "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
  "copy":{
    "name": "peLoop",
    "count": "[mul(length(parameters('vnetArray')), length(parameters('subnetArray')))]"
  },
  "name": "[concat(parameters('subnetArray')[mod(copyIndex('peLoop'), length(parameters('subnetArray')))], '-mongo-pe-', replace(parameters('vnetArray')[div(copyIndex('peLoop'), length(parameters('subnetArray')))], 'Vnet-', ''))]",
  "location": "East US",
  "properties": {
"privateLinkServiceConnections": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('privateEndpointName')]",
            "properties": {
              "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', variables('privateEndpointName'))]"
          }
          }
  ]
  }
}]
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks. But I have other doubt .If those 5 vnets belong to different  RG and regions that would also be stored in an array. For example:
regions[east,east,east,west,west] [rg1.rg2,rg3,rg4,rg5] how the subnet loops iterates when you define the subnet part of each PR? how is going to iterate?
"subnet": {
id": "[resourceId(parameters('rgarrayvnetarray')[copyIndex('rgvnet')],  'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetArray')[copyIndex('privateEndpointLoop')], parameters('subnetArray')[copyIndex()])]

How loop iterate on each vnet with own rg and subnet

Comment: In that case you have to iterate the resource group also if those are existed in different ones. @Zucoa